# ActionScritp 3 removeChild in loop

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have two arrays, fireballs and gombas (enemies).
When I create fireball and gomba, I add them into arrays using push();

I shoot fireballs and move gombas using foor loop

```
for (var f:int = 0; f < fireballs.length; f++)
{
    // move fireballs
}
```

I also remove fireballs if it goes too far, for example

```
if (myFireball.x + 1000 < player.x)
{
    if (myFireball.parent)
    {
        myFireball.parent.removeChild(myFireball);
        fireballs.splice(myFireball, 1);
    }
}
```

I have no problem removing fireballs, but if fireball hitTestObject gomba, I want to remove both, fireball and gomba, ant thats my problem.

I tried on this way and I get error, a term is undefined and has no properties

```
for (i = 0; i < fireballs.length; i++)
{
    for (var m = 0; m < gombas.length; m++)
    {
        if (fireballs[i].hitTestObject(gombas[m]))
        {
        if (fireballs[i].parent)
            {
                fireballs[i].parent.removeChild(fireballs[i]);
                // same for gombas
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I use same loop but just check if fireballs and gombas are visible, if fireballs hit gombas I set visible to false and it works ok. Why it wont work with removeChild.

Comment: Sorry for adding code on this way.

Comment: Please include your code as an actual snippet. It's pretty much unreadable, but I'm going to go ahead and guess your problem is you should be iterating through the array *backwards* when you are removing things

Comment: @user2592722 To post code snippets by themselves, put them on their own lines, with at least one blank line between them anything above them, with each line starting with four blank spaces.  To post code snippets in the middle of regular text, place the ` character both before and after.

Comment: I also tried iterating trouhg the array backwards and it does not help.

Comment: is your fireball hitting mutliple gombas mby?

Comment: I tried to hit only one gomba and there is error. I have now 3 gombas, I tested all of them and only if I hit 3. gomba everything is ok, gomba 1 and 2 gives me error. Cant believe this.

Comment: can you update the code with the `//same for gombas` part actually there pls?

Comment: I just type if (gombas[m].parent) { gombas[m].parent.removeChild(gombas[m]);

Comment: Its another if statement below this "if (fireballs[i].parent)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @itcouldevenbeaboat says, when looping through an array and removing objects, it's better to loop backwards; that way, you won't have index issues.

For example, with the array `["one","two","three"]`, if you looped through and removed like so:

```
for( var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ )
    myArray.splice( i, 1 );
```

What's happening, is this:

- `i` starts at `0`, which points to `"one"`
- we remove the object at position `0` from `myArray`
- `myArray` is now `["two","three"]`
- at the end of the loop, `i` is incremented, and becomes `1`
- we start the next iteraction, and `i` is `1`, which points to `"three"`

In this example, we've skipped over the `"two"` String, because the `splice` has modified the array we're iterating. If we went backwards:

```
for( var i:int = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    myArray.splice( i, 1 );
```

Then we get this:

- `i` starts at `2`, which points to `"three"`
- we remove the object at position `2` from `myArray`
- `myArray` is now `["one","two"]`
- at the end of the loop, `i` is decremented, and becomes `1`
- we start the next iteraction, and `i` is `1`, which points to `"two"`

Thus we remove all the objects from `myArray`, no problem.

For your particular example, as you're removing objects from the two arrays, you should iterate backwards, which should give you something like:

```
outer: for ( var i:int = fireballs.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
{
    for ( var m:int = gombas.length - 1; m >= 0; m-- )
    {
        if (fireballs[i].hitTestObject(gombas[m]))
        {
            // remove our fireball and gombas graphics
            if( fireballs[i].parent != null )
                fireballs[i].parent.removeChild( fireballs[i] );
            if( gombas[m].parent != null )
                gombas[m].parent.removeChild( gombas[i] );

            // remove the fireball and gombas from the array; this is assuming
            // that once a fireball hits a gomba, they both disappear
            gombas.splice( m, 1 );
            fireballs.splice( i, 1 );

            // break to the outer loop; the fireballs one, as we don't need
            // to go any further in the inner one
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `outer` label on the `fireballs` loop; this lets us jump out once we detect a collision between a `fireball` and a `gomba`.

If you want a `fireball` to hit multiple `gombas`, then just don't remove the graphics or splice the array.